# Angular - How to expand table

Tags: html, css, angular

I need help expanding a table. For example, when I click on the full-screen icon the table covers the whole page. I'm trying to do this way but it's not working, I didn't get any errors, but the script is working because is changing the class name.
These are the codes. The ***card.component.html*** file is the model that complements the ***dashboard.component.html***. The
***card.component.ts*** has the full-screen code, and ***dashboard.component.html*** has the table.

File **card.component.html**

```
<div class="card {{ fullCard }} {{ cardLoad }}" [@cardClose]="cardClose"
  [ngClass]="cardClass">
  <div class="card-header" *ngIf="title">
    <h5>{{ title }}</h5>
    <span *ngIf="!classHeader">{{ headerContent }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="classHeader">
      <ng-content select=".code-header"></ng-content>
    </span>
    <div class="card-header-right">
      <ul class="list-unstyled card-option">
        <li *ngIf="!isCardToggled" (click)="this.isCardToggled=
          !this.isCardToggled"><i class="icofont icofont-simple-left"></i></li>
        <li *ngIf="isCardToggled" (click)="this.isCardToggled=
          !this.isCardToggled"><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i></li>
        <li *ngIf="isCardToggled"><i class="icofont icofont-maximize {{
            fullCardIcon }} full-card" (click)="fullScreen($event)"></i></li>
        <li *ngIf="isCardToggled"><i class="icofont icofont-minus minimize-card"
            appCardToggleEvent (click)="toggleCard($event)"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div [@cardToggle]="cardToggle">
    <div class="card-body" [ngClass]="blockClass">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-loader" *ngIf="loadCard"><i class="icofont icofont-refresh
      rotate-refresh"></i></div>
</div>
```

File **card.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {cardToggle, cardClose} from './card-animation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss'],
  animations: [cardToggle, cardClose],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() headerContent: string;
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() blockClass: string;
  @Input() cardClass: string;
  @Input() classHeader = false;
  cardToggle = 'expanded';
  cardClose = 'open';
  fullCard: string;
  fullCardIcon: string;
  loadCard = false;
  isCardToggled = false;
  cardLoad: string;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  toggleCard(event: any) {
    this.cardToggle = this.cardToggle === 'collapsed' ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed';
  }

  closeCard(event: any) {
    this.cardClose = this.cardClose === 'closed' ? 'open' : 'closed';
  }

  fullScreen(event: any) {
    this.fullCard = this.fullCard === 'full-card' ? '' : 'full-card';
    this.fullCardIcon = this.fullCardIcon === 'icofont-resize' ? '' : 'icofont-resize';
  }

  appCardRefresh() {
    this.loadCard = true;
    this.cardLoad = 'card-load';
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.cardLoad = '';
      this.loadCard = false;
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

File **dashboard.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xl-8 left">
    <app-card [title]="'Squads Information'"
      [cardClass]="'project-task'" [blockClass]="'p-b-10'">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Squad</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                     <div class="task-contain">
                         <h6 class="bg-c-blue d-inline-block text-center">A</h6>
                         <p class="d-inline-block m-l-60 table-text">AG Technology I</p>
                     </div>
                 </td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
   <app-card>
</div
```

File **styles.scss**

```
.pcoded {
  .card {
    &.full-card {
      position: fixed;
      top: 80px;
      z-index: 99999;
      box-shadow: none;
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      width: calc(100vw - 287px);
      height: calc(100vh - 80px);
      &.card-load {
        position: fixed;
      }
    }
    &.card-load {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      .card-loader {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        z-index: 999;
        i {
          margin: 0 auto;
          color: #ab7967;
          font-size: 20px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  &[vertical-nav-type="expanded"] .card.full-card {
    width: calc(100vw - 287px);
  }
  &[vertical-nav-type="collapsed"] .card.full-card {
    width: calc(100vw - 97px);
  }
  &[vertical-nav-type="offcanvas"] .card.full-card {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: I don't know how to use that, sorry! Is there any other way to help me?